# Windows server backup in bare metal recovery mode fails on hidden partition with message "the system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: backup, windows-server

Attempting a "bare metal recovery" backup on a Windows DC (Server 2019 Std) using Windows Server Backup, the backup fails when attempting to create an image for the hidden 500MB "Recovery" partition.  The error log simply states:

> Backup of volume \?\Volume{}\ has failed. The system cannot find the file specified.

Because this is happening on an unmounted volume there is seemingly little that can be done to address the issue, and the error message itself is less than helpful since it doesn't even identify a file or path within the volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the search hits I found applied to my specific case, nor did any one answer get me to the fix on its own, hence this self-answered question which will hopefully help anyone else with the same issue.

For me, the solution was as follows, and thankfully does not require a reboot:

1. **Mount the hidden volume and assign a drive letter** - in my case this was not possible from Disk Manager (all menu entries except 'Help' were missing from the right-click menu for the problem partition, and even that was greyed out) but ymmv so you might want to try it that way first.

   1. Open an elevated command shell
   2. `DISKPART`
   3. `LIST DISK` to get disk number `d` which hosts the problem partition
   4. `SELECT DISK d`
   5. `LIST PARTITION` and identify your problem partition number `p` from the list
   6. `SELECT PARTITION p`
   7. `ASSIGN` to mount the volume and assign next available drive letter
   8. `EXIT` to leave DISKPART (keep elevated command shell open)
2. **Run CHKDSK "offline scan and fix" on the newly-mounted volume**

   1. e.g. if your assigned drive letter is H, then `CHKDSK H: /OFFLINESCANANDFIX`

      *Note: In my case, CHKDSK output reported no problems with the volume or its file system, however running the scan did fix the backup issue.*
3. **Unmount the volume**

   1. `DISKPART`
   2. `SELECT DISK d`
   3. `SELECT PARTITION p`
   4. `REMOVE` to unassign the drive letter
   5. `EXIT` to leave DiskPart
   6. `EXIT` again to close the command shell
4. **Delete backup target**

   1. Use Windows Explorer or whatever to browse to your backup target volume, wherever that is (e.g. removable drive)
   2. Go into directory "WindowsImageBackup"
   3. Delete the entire subdirectory which matches the hostname of the computer you are backing up.  If you don't do this, the backup will fail with "The mounted backup volume is inaccessible."
5. **Run backup**